# How to check if an object property exists, and conditionally assign default value (in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to check for an object property and conditionally assign a default value.

This seems clunky:

```
if (!obj.prop) obj.prop = defaultProp;
```

A cleaner option is this:

```
obj.prop = (obj.prop) || defaultProp;
```

but the true evaluation performs an unnecessary assignment, so seems like there's gotta be something better?

thanks!

Comment: Not sure what 3rd option you're trying to think of. Either conditional assignment or assignment with possible overwriting-by-self. What else is there?

Comment: If you're using ES6, you could use default parameters perhaps, but otherwise I would prefer your `if` statement.

Comment: Lots of values would return falsy using either approach

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default value of javascript object attributes](//stackoverflow.com/q/6600868)

Answer (score 2):

I'd be careful with this solution using `||` if the `prop` value is falsy ie `undefined` or `null` you will reassign the default value. A good call here is to use `in` operator like so

```
if (!('prop' in obj)) obj.prop = defaultProp;
```

Please note that inside the condition `'prop'` is a string representing the exact name of the property that you want to check for.